.NET Core: why is appsettings.{environment}.json failing to inherit from parent appsettings.json?
My understanding is that, in .NET Core, child appsettings files, e.g. appsettings.development.json, inherit from the parent appsettings.json (in much the same way that, say, C# derived classes inherit all members from parent classes, unless explicitly overridden) - as long as in your startup logic you include code like the following:
IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("parent_appsettings")
    .AddJsonFile("child_appsettings");
    
configbuilder.Build();

This is not happening, however, in my situation.  I have a parent appsettings.json defined somewhat like the following:
{
  "Section1" {
    "Key1": "Value1"
  },
  "Section2" {
    "Key2": "Value2"
  }
}

And in my child appsettings.development.json I have something like this:
{
  "Section2" {
    "Key2": "OverriddenValue2"
  }
}

While this works when I run config.GetSection("Section2").GetValue("Key2") (i,e, the value OverriddenValue2 is returned), it does not work when I try config.GetSection("Section1").GetValue("Key1").  It thinks the section/key is missing, instead of automatically pulling down the section/value from the parent appsettings.
Is this how it's supposed to work?

Does it work, if you out comment/remove your child? Actually it should work as you expect.

Also where does your config come from? Is it the same instance? Have you tried var config = configbuilder.Build();?

Minor point: Inheritance is (probably) not the right concept, btw, although your expectation is correct. Its more about the priority given to configuration sources. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration Are you getting other configuration values from appsettings.json here? Left field thinking but it is possible for this key to be overridden but other configuration providers with higher priority! Sometimes I have tried debugging the configuration provider directly to see what get's loaded (confusing-usually, informative-sometimes)

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.  The issue ended up being a typo; it turns out that Section1 in the parent appsettings was nested inside another section, whereas in the child it was at the root level.
